# Calling method within block in appDelegate

Tags: objective-c, parse-platform, objective-c-blocks

I'm developing an app that responds to Parse push notifications. At some point in the app, I want to press the push notification sent by another user and this should redirect me to third ViewController (tab) in my TabBarController, and I want to display a view in that tab.

```
[query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error){
    if (!error && [PFUser currentUser]) {
       //Display the TabBarController
       UIViewController *controller = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
       controller = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"TabBar"];
       self.window.rootViewController = controller;
       [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
       //Display the third tab
       self.tabBarController = (TabBarViewController *)self.window.rootViewController;
       self.tabBarController.delegate = (id)self;
       self.tabBarController.selectedIndex = 2;

       [self.tabBarController display];


    }
    else{
       NSLog(@"%@", error);
    }

}];
```

I am querying the user that sent me the notification and after completion of querying, I want to display the user's username in a Label in the ViewController of my TabBarContoller. (But say for simplicity I just want to display a view in the third tab for now).

I tried executing the same lines of code outside of the block and it worked, however for some reason when I try to execute [self.tabBarController display] inside the block, it doesn't work.

I also tried:

```
__block TabBarViewController* blocksafeSelf = self.tabBarController;

....

....

[blocksafeSelf display];
```

but it didn't work!

I've been searching for hours on how to solve it! Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try putting

```
dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    [self.tabBarController display];
});
```

in your original method, it seems like you are doing UI updates on a background thread which can cause strange things to happen

Comment: else try put everything in the block i just mentioned and see if that works and go from there

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but unfortunately it didn't work. If i put everything inside the block the app just has a black screen and crashes after a while. I also tried using [self.tabBarController performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(display) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO] but without any luck.

Comment: I found out what the problem was!! I have one line of code that tries to extract the first index of the array objects (which was always being nil due to a bug) and for some reason it was blocking any lines following that. I didn't know it would be relevant to add so I removed it from the post.